# Formatting and inserting a parameter table into a plot

Tags: plotting, output-formatting, fitting

I'm fitting data, and I want to put the parameter table generated by `NoninearModelFit` into the plot. How can I do that in a reasonable way? I want to format the parameter table so that it only shows two decimal places and doesn't show the t-statistic and P-Values.

Comment: You might look at using a combination of Epilog and Inset in your plot.

Comment: Posting some code would be very useful, if only to save us time making up bogus data.

Comment: @YvesKlett I post an answer to illustrate extracting values from model object, then a way to format numbers, then Inset...this seemed long for comment...but agree entirely with your comments on this and some similar questions...there seems to be something in  the 'weather'. Fortunately, this was code I had lying around.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I post this for illustrative purposes. You can access values. I suggest looking at the properties of your model, e.g. if your model is `nlm` then `nlm["Properties"]`.

Some data and model:

```
wd = WeatherData["Brisbane", 
   "Temperature", {{2004, 1, 1}, {2013, 12, 31}, "Day"}];
vl = QuantityMagnitude /@ wd["Values"];
bnl = NonlinearModelFit[Thread[{Range[Length[vl]], vl}], 
   a + d Cos[b x + c], {{a, 20}, {b, Pi/180}, {c, 2}, {d, 10}}, x];
param = bnl["ParameterTableEntries"];
```

Visualizing:

```
pl = Plot[bnl[x], {x, 1, 3600}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}, 
   Epilog -> 
    Inset[Grid[
      Join @@@ 
       Thread[{{{a}, {b}, {c}, {d}}, 
         Map[NumberForm[#, 2] &, param[[All, {1, 2}]], {2}]}], 
      Frame -> True], {2000, 6}], PlotRange -> {0, 35}, 
   PlotLabel -> TraditionalForm[a + d Cos[b x + c]]];
cp = Show[pl, ListPlot[vl], Frame -> True]
```

[image]

The inset has parameter estimate and standard error. This could grid could have been in much better ways and note the order of graphics in `Show` is important. This could be made "nicer" to suit personal preferences and style. I just post it as motivation.

**Post script**: as m_goldberg correctly comments the function produces 2 significant figures not two decimal places). Feel free to adapt as seen fit.

Comment: +1. I hate to be spoil-sport, but the OP asked for two decimal places, not two significant figures. Personally, I think two  significant figures would be more useful.

Comment: @m_goldberg well spotted (as usual)...just adapted some "code lying around"...will add a comment